# Do I need a serious reason to enter a US Embassy as a US Citizen?

Tags: us-citizens, embassies

Out of curiosity, can I, as a US citizen, enter a US embassy without a serious reason? For example, if I was traveling to Tokyo and I want to see what it looks like inside can I just walk in? If not, would it be assumed that it is by per embassy basis and I would need to contact them with my intentions for why I would like to visit?

I don't plan to go to an embassy to hang out or do something inappropriate. I'm genuinely curious about the interiors of the embassy.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. The question seems to be in the nature of the "right" to consular access - is this a right that is actually enforceable *against* your own embassy that may want to stop you from simply wandering the halls trying to pick up hot secretaries (or telling political jokes, or playing loud music, or whatever), or is one's "right" to access the embassy something enforceable only against the *host* country (i.e. the host country can't stop you from going to your embassy, but your embassy can refuse you access or kick you out)?

Comment: Some embassies have tours occasionally.  I was able to visit the Canadian High Commission in London, UK in 2015 this way.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I'm really not. Of course I wouldn't go there to hang out. Jim's comment is pretty reasonable for an answer.

Comment: An organized tour is open to non US citizens. That’s not what you were asking about. You were referring to a US citizen just walking in to look around. Totally impossible!

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I didn't know that and that that is why I'm asking this question. I also don't see a reason why a USC can't get a tour.

Comment: Consider that embassies and consulates are just like any government office building. Other than the parts that are actually there to provide services to the public, which are only a very small part, and which may in many cases only be accessible with an appointment, you usually can't just wander around the offices and other facilities, especially in this day and age of heightened security measures (and before that, because they may have confidential material, and... because they actually have work to do!).

Comment: OTOH you can basically go and hang out at the Australian embassy in Washington, DC.  It has an art gallery and the entrance requirements are simply having photo ID - you don't even have to be Australian.  Of course you still need to go through security to enter the building and I'm sure security will watch you very closely to ensure you don't stray from that gallery. And yes, I have been there and seen the [this exhibit](https://usa.embassy.gov.au/events/exhibit-whispering-grass)

Comment: You can "visit" the Australian High Commission in London by watching Harry Potter!

Comment: I was invited to a party at a US embassy overseas, there was definitely a procedure to getting in (security and administrative). One of the hors d'oeuvres was miniature hamburgers. I've also had meetings with trade people at my own (Canadian) embassies, If you have something serious to talk about you can make an appointment, but please don't waste their time otherwise. Most of it is really just offices, and if they're doing anything nefarious (likely) you wont see it from a  casual visit.

Comment: Considering that it may take several *months* to get an appointment in some US consulates, your extemporaneous visit, even if officially approved, may not help in any way the people desperately waiting for their legitimate appointment...

Comment: @LampPost "I also don't see a reason why a USC can't get a tour." Why would you expect them to have time to give people tours? Other random government offices don't.

Comment: We had to make an appointment to enter the US embassy in Tokyo (2011). It was about as exciting as the DMV-- just another boring American office, but with courthouse-grade security. Really nothing to see.

Comment: The question details morph into three conflicting questions: *a) Can I visit, as in walk in? b) Do I need a reason? c) Do they do guided tours?*  Some people are objecting to the frivolousness of c), but c) is very different to a), and imposes no overhead on staff (other than security screening). So, which is it: c) or a)? Also, the security overhead of visiting an embassy depends heavily on the country it's in; is Tokyo just an example? Don't try Kabul.

Comment: @smci it's really A. I know it doesn't make any sense for a situation where I can go to an embassy, ask for a tour or look around and everyone drops whatever they are doing. It is more about must I always need a serious government related reason to visit.

Comment: Ok then I suggest you delete the part *"An example would be a tour and if one is given by the embassy"*

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some embassies are significant buildings, architecturally and historically, and a number of significant US government buildings under heavy security do give tours (the US Capitol, the White House, the Bureau of Engraving and Printing, Diplomatic Reception Rooms at the State Department, etc...). I don't think it's unreasonable to think embassies could give tours too.

Comment: @ZachLipton Sure, _some_ embassies are significant buildings and _some_ might give tours, but it's not the sort of thing I'd expect to be commonplace.

Comment: Everybody does. You will be asked by a Marine at the door what your business is. Very politely.

Comment: The title asks the opposite question of the body of the post. The title asks "do I need a reason", the body asks "can I enter without a reason". You might want to edit the post to bring one in line with the other. Otherwise, answers that lead with "Yes" or "No" become confusing to parse initially, as you don't immediately know which question they're agreeing with.

Comment: Some embassies host social events for their expatriate citizens.

Comment: I go to hang out in the cigar lounge.

Comment: Please let us know in this question after CIA done visiting you.

Comment: A lot safer than visiting a Saudi consulate!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It's possible that the answer will vary depending on the specific embassy/consulate, but to use the US Consulates in Australia as an example...

No, you can not.  Even as a US citizen you are required to make an appointment to visit the consulate for non-emergency services.

As stated on the [US Consulates Australian webpage](https://au.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/) :

> To be allowed entry into the U.S. Consulates for routine
>   (non-emergency) services, you must make an appointment online.

There is seemingly an exception here for emergency services, however I doubt they would classify "I just wanna have a look around!" as an "emergency".

The appointment system requires you to enter the purpose of your visit, and once again "just lookin'" isn't on the list.

The equivalent page for [Japan](https://jp.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/) has different text, but still states that you must "schedule an appointment"

It's worth keeping in mind that US consulates have an extremely high level of security, and the answer for other countries consulates/embassy will probably be different.  For example, to access a US Consulate in Australia you need to have an appointment, have your bags X-rays, go through a metal detector, and leave all electronics at the security checkpoint.  By contrast, to access an Australia consulate in the US you need to ring the doorbell (or at least, that's been my experience at the Australian Consulate in San Francisco!)

Comment: +1 Additionally it’s worth noting that outside a tour, even with an appointment you’re only going to see about three rooms (of a 50+ room complex) where appointments are held. So that’s not exactly getting to _look around_.

Comment: I didn't read your last sentence until after I posted my comment above, but the Australian embassy in DC has an art gallery that anyone can come in and see.

Comment: Totally right, I don't think there are any US consulates anywhere that don't enforce an insane level of security.  To renew my passport in Southern France required a very formal appointment, a metal detector, leaving everything behind...  When a few of us were invited by the consul to a meeting on local matters, we had a not-so-funny situation where we couldn't set a meeting time because everyone's cell phone had been held up front.  So after that we just arranged to meet the consul at a cafe :-).

Comment: Having been in the US consolate in Melbourne (for a work visa) I can affirm that you must have an appointment (allow at least 2 weeks lead time) and leave everything but your clothes and paperwork with security. Notably, mobile phones, laptops, etc are not allowed in. However, they bag and tag anything surrenderd to security and you can collect it when you exit no problem.

Comment: Similarly, I’ve been to the Danish embassy-consulate in Beijing and the (erstwhile) Chinese consulate in Copenhagen. In Beijing, there was heavily armed security and screening (despite having an appointment); in Copenhagen, anyone could walk in, and you didn’t need an appointment for the consulate (though you did for the embassy, which is in a separate location). Didn’t even have to ring a doorbell, just walked straight in.

Comment: @Harper I did actually laugh out loud at your joke but, damnit, embassies remain the territory of the _host_ country; they merely agree not to enforce their laws there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I've been confused by this in the past, but my understanding is that Harper is correct, and an *embassy* is the territory of its owner, but a *consulate* being the property of its host nation. Is there an authoritative source for this anywhere, in either direction?

Comment: @sharur No, really. Embassies and consulates are all part of the host territory. I'm not sure I can give you an authoritative source but note that Article 22 of the [Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Diplomatic_Relations) states that the premises of a diplomatic mission (embassy, consulate, etc.) must not be entered by the host country without permission. If the embassy was not the territory of the host country, that statement would be redundant: obviously, one country cannot enter the territory of another without permission.

Comment: @sharur See also the sources in the Wikipedia article on [diplomatic missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_mission#Extraterritoriality).

Comment: Do they sell Lamingtons?

Comment: @sharur the grounds of a consulate or embassy are provided as a courtesy by the host country but remain property of the host country. The buildings on that ground may be provided by the host country or constructed by the embassy (in many countries they're existing, often monumental, structures).

Comment: _The answer for other countries consulates/embassy will probably be different_ - when my father was working in Azerbaijan, he regularly visited the Czech consulate for a beer with the consul. I believe it was by invitation, I'd have to ask if it were possible to have a beer with the consul without an appointment.

Comment: @jwenting  Why is this simple concept so difficult to so many people? The physical embassy and its grounds are usually the property of the hosted country, but they are a part of the territory of the host country. It really is just like any home or business: the ownership of the building and land and the territorial jurisdiction are two separate things. The only difference is that diplomatic missions have some protections under the Vienna Convention.

Comment: @DavidRicherby many people assume that you enter the hosted country when entering the embassy grounds. You don't, you are still in the host country but as you say special considerations apply. If they didn't, every marine guard at most embassies around the world would be in prison on weapons charges instantly for example. And there'd be no way for Julian Assange to stay in an embassy in London without being hauled out by Scotland Yard.

Comment: +1. Same in Poland, if it is not an emergency, you need an appointment.

Comment: When I lived in the Netherlands, you could enter the consulate as an ordinary US citizen without an appointment for consular services, but you had to take a number and wait in line.  As an ordinary US citizen, you could not enter the US embassy.  They would turn you away at the security checkpoint.

Comment: The website says they "cannot store" electronic devices. I would interpret that to mean they actually throw your phone away if you "leave [it] at the security checkpoint."

Comment: I would add that "you need an appointment" is not the same as "you can't" ... calling them to say you want to look around may well be allowed

Answer (score 30):

[@Doc provided a very good overall answer.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131187/do-i-need-a-serious-reason-to-enter-a-us-embassy-as-a-us-citizen/131192#131192) I'll add my own experience in the US embassy in London, UK. I have entered the US embassy a number of times as a US citizen for non-emergency situations and I did have to make appointments every time, stating the intended purpose.  Security is high, however it felt that it's not as bad as is sometimes implied.  For example, last time I visited about mid-2018, I could get my mobile phone inside and my laptop - no problem. Yes, they x-rayed my bag and I had to go through the metal detector, but the overall experience seemed less thorough than in an airport. Interestingly, once inside, I was directed to the lift and told to go to floor X for whatever my purpose was.  Nothing and nobody was there to prevent me from going to any other floor. Probably, if I just started wondering around, I would be asked what I was doing there.

Anecdotally, from a friend of mine who spent some time in some rather dangerous countries in Africa and Middle East (Afganistan, Sudan and a few others), he was telling that in most cases simply showing an American passport would get you inside the embassy straight away.  After that they'd ask you the purpose and so on.  He did indicate that in some of the smaller African countries the Embassy staff was more than happy to entertain him as a guest due to lack of any other contact with fellow Americans other than the embassy staff themselves.

Comment: Presumably, when a US citizen shows up unannounced at their embassy in a dangerous country, they're given the benefit of the doubt that it might be an emergency at least long enough to get them inside the building.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's my guess, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I doubt London would classify as a dangerous country for Americans :) Otherwise, of course.

Comment: Aleks, are you sure you could go to other floors? Quite likely either the floors themselves or the elevator lobbies on them would be locked with keycard access. Not been in embassies, but that's common practice in government office buildings I have been to, as well as of course corporate offices where sensitive data is handled.

Comment: Nah, you'd never get past security.  You might get literally "in the front glass door" to the 18 inch space before the security team, depending on the layout.  The US embassy in London has staggeringly high security, its' a prime target for the US' various enemies.

Comment: @Fattie You're probably right. I haven't tried going to a different floor from the one I should have. All I was saying is that once I was in the lift, I was there on my own and there were buttons for other floors as well.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I went to the US embassy in London a few months ago and while I did have an appointment, I don't think anyone asked about it at the door. First I was allowed in by showing my passport, without giving any reason for my visit, and then I was asked when I went up to the consular area. But entering the embassy itself did not require a reason.

Comment: @jwenting It’s possible that security might be after the elevator on other floors. Certainly for any area where classified information is being handled, they wouldn’t just rely on an elevator keycard system.

Comment: @cpast I've worked in government buildings with multiple level security. Key card access to enter the building, then again to enter the elevator to specific floors, and again to enter a specific block of offices on each floor. And on top of that a front desk with guards. It tends to be the same key card, but coded different depending on your access levels. Cards are also fitted with photographs and cameras are everywhere.

Answer (score 14):

This was in 1991, but the U.S. Embassy in Sri Lanka encouraged American ex-pats to go there and register with them.  So that's technically, "a serious reason", but it also seems like a reasonable excuse for just visiting.

Comment: I have seen that same happen with an Australian in the UK, (back in the 1990's.)

Comment: The US now has an [online service](https://step.state.gov/) to do this. At more secure posts, you might not be let in the door without an appointment or an actual emergency.

Answer (score 8):

Security at the US Embassy in Tokyo is pretty buff.
You must have an appointment to visit. You have to make the appointment online.  You can only take a single cellphone, and no other electronics (no, not even a tablet, and not even in substitution for a phone), and no large bags.

https://jp.usembassy.gov/embassy-consulates/tokyo/

If you are going to the Embassy, Japanese police surrounding the place will be very helpful directing you toward the security screening.   If you are not going to the Embassy, they will be very helpful with getting you on your way somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Mind what the embassy is: The embassy is your govenment's office of representative to the other countries government. The, historic, primary job of the ambassador is to serve communication between the governments and telling about the mood. That mood extended to intelligence. Also often embassies do serve cultural relationships or similar.

Especially the part about gathering intelligence obviously isn't public. Around the cultural side there sometimes might be events.

Aside from that are consulates. They are often integrated with an embassy and aimed at general public. Like granting visas and renewing passports. Visiting that is simpler. But as boring as any government office.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really curious, you can schedule an appointment for anything. For example, you want to ask an official if some of your papers are valid or not.

For example, saying that your passport was hurted and you want to ask them if it is still valid.

Probably they will check it, read it, and examine if some biomarker readers are still okay in it. After that, you will leave.

Meanwhile, you also get what you wanted. :-)

(P.s. the US embassy is living from your tax, so doing it *once* is not an ethical breach. Their hard rules are in the fear of some terrorist attacks and not against their own citizens)

Answer (score 1):

To offer some information about other embassies, in my case as an Spaniard National I have visited embassies of Spain in other countries just to meet the personnel.

In countries where the diplomatic mission is very small and the national community they represent is small, the embassy personnel is very open and welcome meeting new visitors.

Particularly, the ones I visited had the consulate section and the embassy within the same building. I could freely step into the consulate part not the embassy part.